# Jmeter - POST API not working

Tags: api, jmeter, http-post, jmeter-3.2

I am new to Jmeter and have been struggling to get it working to test my POST API. It works fine for a GET API call where I pass the parameters through the Parameters tab.

Details here:

server name: localhost
port: 8080
path /registerMobileUsingCode

In the request body, I am sending the following:

{
    "clientName": "DemoOrg",
    "code": "9880007615",
    "languageId": "1"
}

My Jmeter setup looks like this:

[image: 1]

And my HTTP Request Header looks like this:

[image: Request Header details]

The API is in production and works fine with postman.

I am just unable to get it working through JMeter. It is obvious that I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what despite having spent a considerable amount of time Googling for solutions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

## UPDATE - 1 - Updated with jmeter log as suggested

> > Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1 Sample Start: 2017-08-09 17:03:41 IST Load time: 1604 Connect Time: 1525 Latency: 1604 Size in bytes: 399
> >     Sent bytes:251 Headers size in bytes: 213 Body size in bytes: 186
> >     Sample Count: 1 Error Count: 1 Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
> >     Response code: 500 Response message: Server Level Exception
> >     encountered
>
> Response headers: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Level Exception encountered
>   Date: Wed, 09 Aug 2017 11:33:43 GMT Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Server:
>   Jetty(9.2.16.v20160414)
>
> HTTPSampleResult fields: ContentType: application/json DataEncoding:
>   null

## UPDATE-2 - Using Postman and JMeter Recorder

As suggested by @Dimitri T, I downloaded the Linux version of Postman and started it with  --proxy-server=localhost:8888.

I was now able to make a Postman request and capture the request in JMeter. Here is what the request looked like:

[Jmeter capture of a Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Id2.png)

As you can see, nothing radically different from what I did. However, this DOES work! So hurray!

Comment: Also, please update your question with Jmeter log

Comment: Do you have a working curl for your request, if you do please share it with us

Comment: Add a View Result  Tree (right click on your thread group > Add > Listener > View Result Tree, then try to send your request, you will find the request under the result tree, with request/response...

Comment: Have updated with the logs as suggested by Adnan and @QuakeCore ,Isee a 500 error which is what my server returns anyway.

Comment: 500 response indicates a general failure at the server side, I would be checking the server logs if I were u

Comment: Hi @QuakeCore I do know why the 500 error is being returned from the server. It is because the server is looking for "clientName" and "code" from request.getParameter('clientName') or request.getParameter('code'), but the parameters are just not coming through in the request. This is already in our production system and is working properly. This is also working through postman as I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If your application works fine with Postman the fastest and the easiest way of building JMeter test plan will be just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

1. Prepare JMeter for recording (you can do it in a few clicks via [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature))

   - from JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Expand `Workbench - HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Prepare Postman for recording

   - In order to "tell" Postman to use JMeter as a proxy you need to provide **--proxy-server** parameter to it like:

     ```
     C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Postman\app-x.x.x\Postman.exe --proxy-server=localhost:8888
     ```
3. Execute your requests in Postman
4. JMeter will capture requests, convert them into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and store them under `Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller`

References:

- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [How to configure Postman Native Client App to use an external proxy](http://blog.eviltester.com/2016/12/how-to-configure-postman-native-client.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. I am on Ubuntu and struggling with getting JMeter to record the postmal pings. I have the Recorder started and the system-wide proxy setups done. But I can't see the Postman requests getting captured.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the image you have attached you are missing **/** in the path.

the path should be **/registerMobileUsingCode**

1. if it is working fine from POSTMAN, then your port 8080 is fine.
2. Can you please confirm what is the data type of your request? looks like languageId is integer so you should be **using languageId: 1**, instead of languageId: "1". The integer should not be double quotes.